# Mouse pointer/cursor pointing to webelement apart from Actions class in Selenium

Tags: selenium

[image]I am well aware that we can use Actions class to move to a particular web element as below.

```
Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("element"))).build().perform();
```

For one of the webelement as soon as I move to that element I should get a dropdown. But some times this is working and some times not. Is there any option other than Actions class to simulate mouse movement to particular webelement?

The HTML code for the element I am trying to simulate mouse pointer movement to it is one with class="dropdown-submenu"

```
<li ng-show="setStatusPermission" class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="">Set status</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li ng-show="activePermission" class=""><a href="" data-ng-click="invokeTaskAction(taskDetails.id,'setStatus','active',true)">Active</a></li>
        <li ng-show="cancelPermission" class=""><a href="" data-ng-click="invokeTaskAction(taskDetails.id,'setStatus','cancelled',true)">Cancelled</a></li>
        <li ng-show="completePermission" class="ng-hide"><a href="" data-ng-click="invokeTaskAction(taskDetails.id,'setStatus','completed',true)">Completed</a></li>
        <li ng-show="errorPermission" class="ng-hide"><a href="" data-ng-click="invokeTaskAction(taskDetails.id,'setStatus','error',true)">Error</a></li>
        <li ng-show="expiredPermission" class="ng-hide"><a href="" data-ng-click="invokeTaskAction(taskDetails.id,'setStatus','expired',true)">Expired</a></li>
        <li ng-show="suspendPermission" class="ng-hide"><a href="" data-ng-click="invokeTaskAction(taskDetails.id,'setStatus','suspended',true)">Suspended</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Automation code snipet to perform the operations is as below.

```
WebElement webElementSetStatus = basePage.waitForElementToLoadAndReturnWebElement_BasePage(
            bc_ui_TaskAction_Setstatus, "linkText", "15");
        basePage.getActions_BasePage().moveToElement(webElementSetStatus).build().perform();
        List<WebElement> options = basePage.getWebElements_BasePage(
            "#bc-td-actions-dropdown-list > li.dropdown-submenu > ul > li", "cssSelector");
        for (WebElement option : options)
        if (!option.getAttribute("class").equals("ng-hide") && !option.getText().isEmpty())
            actualAvailableStatusOptions.add(option.getText());
```

Comment: Actions is the way to do this... please post more of your code that is failing so we can help find the problem.

Comment: When you post HTML, please use a beautfier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to reformat the HTML properly. Also, you can use 4 spaces at the start of a line to format code blocks.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for beautifying the code :)

Comment: Hi Jeff,
I am using actions class to perform mouse hover  over the element named "Set Status"
After mouse hover I should get a dropdown as attached in the screenshot.

Comment: I have tried mouseover operation and still no success
String script = "jQuery('li[ng-show=\"setStatusPermission\"]').mouseover()";
basePage.executeJavascript(script);